# Execute multiple variable query in SQL Server using Python cursor

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I'm trying to execute multiple queries in SQL Server using the pymssql library.

This is my code:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("DECLARE @begin_time datetime, @end_time datetime, @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10);  
             SET @begin_time = DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) ;  
             SET @end_time = GETDATE(); 
             SET @from_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than or equal', @begin_time);  
             SET @to_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal', @end_time);
             SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_users(@from_lsn, @to_lsn, 'all');")
output = cur.fetchall()
print(output)
conn.close()
```

The code is running fine and fetching the result, however when I'm calculating the date using Python library and passing it to the code, I'm getting an error.

Sample code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
end_date = datetime.now()
start_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=-1)

cur = conn.cursor()
query =  f"""DECLARE @begin_time datetime, @end_time datetime, @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10);  
                SET @begin_time = {start_date};  
                SET @end_time = {end_date}; 
                SET @from_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than or equal', @begin_time);  
                SET @to_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal', @end_time); 
                SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_users (@from_lsn, @to_lsn, 'all');"""
print(query)
cur.execute(query)
output = cur.fetchall()
print(output)
conn.close()
```

Error:

> **ProgrammingError**: (102, Incorrect syntax near '11'.
>
> DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:
> General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Would really appreciate if someone can help me and explain the issue.

Comment: the error message is revealing that its an incorrect syntax

Comment: thats what i'm not able to figure out where i'm getting incorrect syntax, as same query is working fine when i'm calculating time with sql query.

Comment: This is possibly because of the way the dateformat is being passed to sql server block. can you pass start_time in the YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss format

Comment: i have tried that but it didn't worked :(

Comment: When you print the query are your date values wrapped in `'` characters? You could try using [Binding Parameters](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Binding-Parameters) to ensure that they are handled correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider actual SQL parameterization of the time variables and not string interpolation or concatenation with F-strings which generally is not safe or efficient for passing values from application layer to backend database. The library, `pymssql`, supports [parameters](http://www.pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html). Python's `datetime.datetime` should translate to MSSQL's `DATETIME`.

```py
# PREPARED STATEMENTS WITH %s PLACEHOLDERS
query = """DECLARE @begin_time datetime, @end_time datetime, @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10);  
           SET @begin_time = %s;  
           SET @end_time = %s; 
           SET @from_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than or equal', @begin_time);  
           SET @to_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal', @end_time); 
           SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_users (@from_lsn, @to_lsn, 'all');
        """
print(query)

# EXECUTE QUERY WITH BINDED PARAMS
cur.execute(query, [start_date, end_date])
```

In fact, you can shorten the query since parameters do not need declaration:

```
# PREPARED STATEMENTS WITH %s PLACEHOLDERS
query = """DECLARE @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10);
           SET @from_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than or equal', %s);  
           SET @to_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal', %s); 
           SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_users (@from_lsn, @to_lsn, 'all');
        """
```

By the way, please note `pymmsql` is no longer a maintained library. Consider `pyodbc` for most secure, updated DB-API for Python-SQL Server connections. But note the parameter placeholder for pyodbc is qmarks `?` and not `%s` (unlike most Python DB-APIs).

Comment: Glad to help! Happy coding!